# Carbon difference of now() vs datetime with "ago" using diffForHumans() method

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

According to the manual: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

to get an `ago`

> When comparing a value in the past to default now

but whatever I do, I cannot get the `ago`

`return $datetime->diffForHumans(Carbon::now())`

results to `before`, while

`return Carbon::now()->diffForHumans($datetime);`

results to `after`,

but as you can see clearly both of my snippet above compares the `past`($datetime) and to default now (Carbon::now()) so I cannot understand why I can't get an ago? Hope somebody can help. I just need to echo `ago`. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `diffForHumans()` without arguments and after the 'date calculation', like:

```
Carbon::now()->subDays(24)->diffForHumans();  // "3 weeks ago"
```

or, if you have a date, you can just use use `$datetime->diffForHumans();` :

```
$datetime = Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 8, 25); // or your $datetime of course
return $datetime->diffForHumans();  // "1 week ago"
```

Comment: can you change the "1 week ago" for the date? I want to show the date as soon as the week passed. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

While @baao gave a great answer but the `Carbon::createFromDate()` function can be problematic if you are passing a raw date input say Laravels `created_at`. Now you have to use a different function. Take a look below.

```
$carbondate = Carbon::parse($users->created_at); 
$past = $carbondate->diffForHumans();
dd($past);
```

Where `$users->created_at` is  a date like `2018-05-03 14:54:14` , This will then give an answer like 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Laravel provides `created_at` as a Carbon instance, so you can in fact simply call `$model->updated_at->diffForHumans();`.